# Is it bad practice to use var keyword in Dart

Tags: dart

I am using var keyword often. But I read that if I use var keyword, this variable allocates much space as it can. So if I declare integer like `int a = 1;` will my program be performant than `var a = 1`; ? Is this information are true? I searched it but didn't find any results about this. I know it is a stupid question but i'm confused.

Comment: Where did you read that? Could you share the resource? I don't believe that is true because dart can infer the type

Comment: @RohanThacker at a telegram group but I dont remember that group. It wasnt an article or something but when i read this i got confused

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no difference between writing `int a = 1;` and `var a = 1;`.

In the latter case, *type inference* is applied, by the compiler, to infer the declared type of the variable. The inferred type is taken from the type of the initializing expression, which is an `int`, so after type inference, `var a = 1;` becomes `int a = 1;`.

There are places where using `var` is unnecessary (function arguments, like `int foo(var x) => x.toString().length;`, where the `var` is unnecessary and can be removed), and places where it's not going to give you what you want (`double x = 1;` does not mean the same as `var x = 1;` because the latter infers a the variable to have type `int`, and the former infers `1` to be a `double` literal.)

In most cases, using `var` is fine. The style guide even [recommends it](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#dont-redundantly-type-annotate-initialized-local-variables) over the redundant `int x = 1;`.

Also, about allocating *space*, all Dart objects will likely take up the same space. All values are object references, even integers, and all object references take up the same space (the objects themselves also take up space, but that's independent of how you declare the variables referring to that object).

What can happen is that a compiler sees that a variable only contains integers, maybe only *small* integers, like the loop variable `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) ...`. Then the compiler can optimize the way it stores that integer. A good compiler can do that even if you declare the variable as `(dynamic i = 0; i < 10; i++)` because it can see that only small integers are ever stored in that variable, so again the *declaration* doesn't matter as much, as long as the compiler can see which values are *actually* stored.

Comment: can i ask a question? Is there anything like `let` in dart? cause they have `var` here.

Comment: What do you mean by `"let"`? (Many languages have something named `let`, and they don't all mean the same thing.)

Comment: `let` decrale a variable in block scoped and can redecrale in differences(or child) block scoped. like `let` in javascript.

Comment: Dart's `var` is like JavaScript's `let`. It's a block-scoped local variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Not a stupid question at all, the use of int a = 1 or string a = "one" is wise when knowing what value you will be dealing with - every variable has a job, when you know what indefinitely you'll be working with integers, strings, doubles, floats, booleans, etc. it is recommended practice to declare the appropriate type (down the line it pays off as you debug as well, most IDEs assist when coding with specific variable types, more readable, more information) - the use of var a = 1, or 'var' in general is when you don't exactly know what the job of the variable will be, as in it could store anything from a boolean true/false, or maybe a number, or maybe a string of characters - by declaring it as a universal variable you are basically giving it the type of possibly anything. It's not "wrong", but not ideal either if you know exactly what you are working with - that's why we have all these unique variable types.